# Windows event viewer application logs lost after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, uninstall, eventviewer

I need to check event viewer's application logs for uninstall events.
So, I filtered them on MSIInstaller. Turns out I can see logs only upto last reboot which was just a few hours ago from writting this question.
But I need to see logs upto last 30 days.

Can anyone help me out here ?
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: What are the settings/properties for the applog (right click on the log and choose settings/properties)?  Is it just one server that exhibits this behavior?  If you don't filter on MSIInstaller does it show events back far enough in the GUI?  Maybe your filter isn't right.

Comment: Even if I do not filter on MSIInstaller the log is upto last reboot only....which property do you want me to look at ?

Answer (score 0):

See if you're not filtering your logs on date.

Also in eventvwr.msc (Event Viewer) go to View->Filter->General(tab) and check out your log size and overwrite settings

Regards,

Comment: No I am not filtering on dates...that I have checked already...but I cant find General tab you are talking about...I am using windows server 2008 r2

Comment: Sorry that was on XP, I thought it was pretty similar on all newer versions of windows too. Have a look in group policies then(AD or gpedit.msc). There should be the settings for Event Log service.

Comment: No luck mate...cant find it anywhere...but apparently all the other system and security logs exists for more than 10 days atleast.